# How to convert floating point value into decimal value in open office?

Tags: openoffice.org

In spreadsheet i have more than 5 columns, every columns showing its own value. One of the column shows the talk time as follows,

```
60:00       
06:44  
08:48     
59:13
```

I just want to round up this values, as follows.

```
60     
07       
09     
59
```

For example `01:25` If the talktime is equal to & above 25seconds it should be rounded as `02` but if the talktime is `01:13` then it should round it as `01` and not as `02`.

Comment: Normally, I'd expect to round up after 30 seconds. It sounds like you're trying to give folks a 25 second grace period. If that's the case you're definitely going to need a formula, as suggested by @MestreLion

Comment: @Amanda: he is going to need a formula anyway, since he wants to extraxt just the minutes, and MM alone is not a valid format (it gives me weird results). Must be either HH:MM or MM:SS. Also, HH:MM does **not** round up. So 00:06:59 becomes 00:06, not 00:07

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to fiddle with `Format -> Cell` with no sucess. The problem is OpenOffice treats XX:YY values as hours and minutes, NOT minutes and seconds. But you could try this:

- Input your times with HH:MM:SS format. Like 00:08:48. Say that is A1 cell.
- Add an aditional column, and input thiis formula in (say B1):

  ```
  =minute(A1)+if(second(A1)>=25,1,0)
  ```
- Or, if you dont like adding "00:" to all values, and dont mind OO interpreting it as HH:MM, use this formula instead:

  ```
  =hour(A1)+if(minute(A1)>=25,1,0)
  ```
- If you dont like using 2 columns for 1 value (1 for "raw", real value and the other for the formmated value), just right-click the undesirable column and select `Hide`

Comment: When I change the format to simply "MM" it doesn't round off for me--I wind up with six minutes in the second row where it should be rounding up to seven: 
00:06
00:06
00:08
00:59

Comment: As far as I can know, minutes (or hours) are never automatically rounded up. Using format strings alone, with no formulas, will always simply truncate the seconds (or minutes)

Answer (score 1):

If the values are all in place already and it is too late to input the times as HH:MM:SS, here's what did work for me:

```
=IF(VALUE(RIGHT(TRIM(A1),2))>25,SUM(LEFT(TRIM(A1),2)+1),LEFT(TRIM(A1),2))
```

Crazy, right? I cut and pasted the values, which had a lot of trailing spaces, so I needed "TRIM()" but this says that if the number composed of the two rightmost characters is greater than 25, show the minutes. Otherwise, add 1.

Comment: I dont see the point in fiddling with VALUE, RIGHT, LEFT and all this manual (and error-prone) parsing when the MINUTE/SECOND functions will do that for you.

Comment: It depends on whether Calc knows it is looking at minutes and seconds.

Comment: it will know if you input data as 00:06:45

Comment: That's true. So if it isn't too late to input the data in HH:MM:SS, that's the other option.